# Chamando uma função só de atualizar a página

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte HTML que chama um função JavaScript:

```
 <div>
  <button id="avancar-aula">Avançar aula</button> 
 </div>

 <script src="js/avanca-aula.js"></script>
```

E tenho a função JS:

```
let avancarAula = document.querySelector('#avancar-aula');
avancarAula.addEventListener('click', function(evento){

 avancaAula();
});

function avancaAula(){


      let avanca = {

        idUsuario: document.querySelector('#id').textContent,
        token: document.querySelector('#token').textContent,
        id: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula').textContent
      };

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var variavel = document.querySelector('#token-servico').innerHTML;

      xhr.open("POST", "http://54.233.9.248:8080/web/rest/classes/nexts", 
true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + variavel);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){

      if(xhr.status == 200){

       console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }

     if(xhr.status =500){
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
   });
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(avanca));
 }
setTimeout(avancaAula, 3000);
```

O meu problema é o seguinte.

Toda vez que eu dou um f5 ele chama a função, tipo que ele clica no botão sozinho. Fiz para que na hora que eu quiser mudar de página eu clico no botão para chamar a ação, mas nem imagino o que está acontecendo para essa função ser chamada no momento em que a página é atualizada. O que pode ser?

Comment: O `setTimeout(avancaAula, 3000); ` está chamando a função quando a página é carregada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...]mas nem imagino o que está acontecendo para essa função ser chamada no
>   momento em que a página é atualizada. O que pode ser?

O `setTimeout(avancaAula, 3000);` irá chamar a função após 3 segundos quando a página é carregada.

Se não deseja que isso ocorra, basta apagar essa linha do `SetTimeout`.

Comment: Sim, testei aqui e é isso realmente, mas eu preciso do setTimeout, como posso substitui-lo?

Comment: Mas vc precisa dele em que ocasião?

Comment: Preciso entender melhor isso para poder saber o que fazer sem ter que apaga-lo.

Comment: É que a função precisa do iID da última aula nesta linha, ID: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula').textContent.... porém, o  ID vem de uma API. Quando a página está carregando, se eu não colocar esse time, ela não consegue pegar o id a tempo. Tipo que carrega a página toda e o ID vem depois. O setTimeout atrasa o carregamento desta função, fazendo com que ela apareça depois que o ID já foi carregado.

Comment: Certo. Essa forma não é a melhor de fazer isso. Vou analisar aqui pra ver o que vc deve fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz "(...) não consegue pegar o id a tempo." - Está a falar disto: `id: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula')` ? Se for o caso é porque o javascript está a executar antes da página carregar, em que a forma correta de resolver é executar no evento `load` da `window`

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz Pra não deixar esta pergunta aberta e como fui o único a responder, seria interessante fechá-la marcando ✓ na resposta. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, pode me chamar a qualquer momento que terei maior prazer em ajudar. ObG!